# Mean and variance of Binomial Distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, means, binomial-distribution, variance

I was reading a paper that gives a dynamic programming model of an R&D project. It said that the performance drift (*the uncertainty in the performance of the product being developed*) follows a binomial distribution. From period `t` to the next period, the performance may unexpectedly improve
with probability `p`, or it may deteriorate with probability `1−p` because of unexpected adverse events. We generalize the binomial distribution by allowing the performance improvement and deterioration, respectively, to be “spread” over the next `N` performance states with transition probabilities.

p<sub>ij</sub> = $p/n$ if $j\in$ {$i+1/2,...,i+n/2$} , $(1-p)/n$ if $j\in$ {$i-1/2,...,i-n/2$}

I understand upto this point.

Now it says that mean of this distribution is $((N + 1)/4)(2p − 1)+i$ and the variance is $((N + 1)/8)(N/3+(N+1)(1/3 −((2p − 1)$<sup>2</sup>$/2)))$

I have no idea how do they get this mean and variance. From what I know about binomial distribution, mean is `np` and variance is `npq`. ($q=1-p$). Can anyone please show how have they derive this mean and variance?

**Edit 1:** p<sub>ij</sub> means probability of going from product performance `i` to product performance `j`. So basically if product performance is `i`at time `t` and `j` at time `t+1` and if $j>i$ then product performance improved and vice-versa. See the left section of this figure and the *Note* underneath to understand the meaning of "spread":

[image]

Comment: I would like to try to answer your question, but I am having difficulty understanding what you mean by 'spread' over the next $N$ performance states and what $p_{ij}$ means. Could you elaborate on these things? Thanks.

Comment: @moorish check edit.

Comment: How about I explain how they calculated the mean, and from this maybe you can try and derive the variance?

Comment: @moorish that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer how they derived the mean or expected value of the distribution, and then I'll leave it to you to derive the variance (it'll involve a similar sort of method).

This is assuming $i=0$ (you can easily prove that for an arbitrary $i$ it just amounts to adding $i$ at the end). Think of this as just 'shifting' the distribution $i$ units to the right (or left).

For a random variable $X$ we define the 'mean' or expected value of $X$ as

$\sum_{\forall x} P(X=x)x$ where $P(X=x)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ takes on the value $x$.

Lets first define the random variable in this scenario, here it is:

$X = {\frac{i}{2}}$, $\forall i \in +/- \{1,2,3,...N\}$

We can also define a probability function for $X$ as

$P(X=x) = {\frac{p}{N}}\\ \forall i \in + \{1,2,...,N\}$

$P(X=x) = {\frac{1-p}{N}} \\ \forall i\in - \{1,2,...,N\}$

So

$E(x) = \sum_{\forall x}P(X=x)x = \sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}\frac{p}{N}\frac{i}{2} + \sum_{i \in \{-1,-2,...,-n\}}\frac{1-p}{N}\frac{i}{2} $

Also,

$\sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}\frac{p}{N}\frac{i}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{p}{N} \sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}{i}$

But $ \sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}{i}$ is just the sum of the first $N$ natural numbers, which is known to be $\LARGE \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$

So $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}\frac{p}{N}\frac{i}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{p}{N} \sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}{i} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{p}{N}\frac{N(N+1)}{2} = \frac{p(N+1)}{4}$

Similarly, we can also show that $\sum_{i \in \{-1,-2,...,-n\}}\frac{1-p}{N}\frac{i}{2} = \frac{p-1(N+1)}{4}$

And so $E(x) =  \sum_{\forall x}P(X=x)x = \sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}\frac{p}{N}\frac{i}{2} + \sum_{i \in \{-1,-2,...,-n\}}\frac{1-p}{N}\frac{i}{2} = \frac{p(N+1)}{4} + \frac{(p-1)(N+1)}{4} = \frac{2p-1(N+1)}{4}$